# Typo3 nested arrays in Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm passing a nested array to my Fluid-Template and now want to iterate over both of them.

Alas, the second for-each only shows the key of the super-array?

The Array (in pseudo-code):

```
[2016]
   [0]
      [title]->test
      [content]->test
   [1]
      [title]->test
      [content]->test
```

And the code in my template:

```
<f:for each="{myArray}" as="topItem" iteration="it1" key="key">

    <h4>{key}</h4>
    <f:for each="{topItem}" as="subItem" iteration="it2">
        {subItem.title}<br />
        {subItem.content}
    </f:for>
</f:for>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Certainly doesn't look wrong - can you show us (a screenshot of) the output of `<f:debug>{myArray}</f:debug>`?

Comment: I managed it to make it work with <'f:groupedFor'> - but thanks for the reply!

Comment: Please accept/close the question - and perhaps add the final code you used to make it work ;)

Comment: Still, the fluid posted here should actually work.

Answer (score 2):

Summary of the comments as answer and examples on both mentioned `f:for` and `f:groupedFor` view-helpers. `f:for` is basically good to any kind of array and allows to iterate over each level of nested data - `f:group` is good to transfor flat data structures into nested data-sets.

### `f:for`

The input array is two-dimensional and looks like the following

```
$this->view->assign('nestedItems', [
    '2016' => [
        ['title' => '1st Title', 'content' => '1st Content'],
        ['title' => '2nd Title', 'content' => '2nd Content'],
    ],
    '2015' => [
        ['title' => '3rd Title', 'content' => '3rd Content'],
        ['title' => '4th Title', 'content' => '4th Content'],
    ],
]);
```

The Fluid template to iterate over that nested data-set looks like this

```
<f:for each="{nestedItems}" as="items" key="currentYear">
    <h2>{currentYear}</h2>
    <f:for each="{items}" as="item">
      <h3>{item.title}</h3>
      <p>{item.content}</p>
    </f:for>
</f:for>
```

### f:groupedFor

The flat input array looks like this (year is now part of each array element)

```
$this->view->assign('flatItems', [
    ['year' => 2016, 'title' => '1st Title', 'content' => '1st Content'],
    ['year' => 2016, 'title' => '2nd Title', 'content' => '2nd Content'],
    ['year' => 2015, 'title' => '3rd Title', 'content' => '3rd Content'],
    ['year' => 2015, 'title' => '4th Title', 'content' => '4th Content'],
]);
```

The Fluid template to iterate over that nested data-set looks like this

```
<f:groupedFor each="{flatItems}" as="items" groupBy="year" groupKey="currentYear">
  <h2>{currentYear}</h2>
  <f:for each="{items}" as="item">
    <h3>{item.title}</h3>
    <p>{item.content}</p>
  </f:for>
</f:groupedFor>
```

### Output for both scenarios

The output is the same in both scenarios

```
<h2>2016</h2>

    <h3>1st Title</h3>
    <p>1st Content</p>

    <h3>2nd Title</h3>
    <p>2nd Content</p>

<h2>2015</h2>

    <h3>3rd Title</h3>
    <p>3rd Content</p>

    <h3>4th Title</h3>
    <p>4th Content</p>
```